# Laravel using select in Eloquent scope and query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to clean up some code that I made.

This is the current code:

```
$message = Message::with('comments')
   ->join('users', 'messages.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
   ->join('team_user', 'messages.created_by', '=', 'team_user.user_id')
   ->join('teams', 'team_user.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
   ->join('roles', 'team_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
   ->select('messages.id',  'messages.message', DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name, " ", users.last_name) AS created_by_name'), DB::raw('CONCAT(roles.name, " ", teams.name) AS function'))
   ->findOrFail($id);
```

I tried to make it like this:

```
$message = Message::with('comments')
   ->join('users', 'messages.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
   ->withFunction()
   ->findOrFail($id);
```

So I made a scope called `withFunction` that looks like this:

```
return $query->join('team_user', 'messages.created_by', '=', 'team_user.user_id')
   ->join('teams', 'team_user.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
   ->join('roles', 'team_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(roles.name, " ", teams.name) AS function'));
```

But because I use this scope where I select specific column, I cant use the select in my query as well. I want it to look like this:

```
$message = Message::with('comments')
   ->join('users', 'messages.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
   ->withFunction()
   ->select('messages.id', 'messages.message')
   ->findOrFail($id);
```

So I specify the columns returned from the scope and from the query itself. I know I can't have 2 select's in a query, but is there any way this would be possible?

Would be great if you could just return columns in the scope to use it through the whole application.

Comment: What is the point to move half of your query in separate method ? 
You can put the how request in a separate Message method and just to call it when you need it. But that is only if its requested at multiple places else just leave it as it is..

Comment: Try using `addSelect()` and let me know if that works. `->withFunction()->addSelect('messages.id', 'messages.message')`

Comment: You can clean complex joins with Eloquent Relation

Comment: @NyanLynnHtut Good idea! Although there's one downside, relations will increase the amount of db queries. (Even though in many cases that doesn't really matter)

Comment: @NyanLynnHtut well how would I create this as a Eloquent Relation. Because I just add a function of a user extra to the normal result. I dont want to have the function queried in every Message model as well.

Comment: @Svetlio Because I dont want the function to be queried when I want to retrieve a specific message.

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to come down to how [get()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1626) works.

```php
    $original = $this->columns;

    if (is_null($original)) {
        $this->columns = $columns;
    }
```

Get only adds the '*' to select if no other selects are defined.

You either need to explicitly call `select('*')` on the builder

```
$message = Message::with('comments')
   ->select('*')
   ->join('users', 'messages.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
   ->withFunction()
   ->select('messages.id', 'messages.message')
   ->findOrFail($id);
```

or add it in in your scope, this is an example from a 5.3 project.

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    if(is_null($builder->getQuery()->columns)){
        $builder->addSelect('*');
    }
    $builder->addSelect(DB::raw('...'));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at [addSelect()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L278). When you use select(), your are overriding all the other selected columns and only selecting the one. By using addSelect() you will append the column to the selected columns rather than replace it.

So as a general rule you should call select() before calling any scopes that add columns, and those scopes should use addSelect().

Also... you actually do not need to return the $query in your scope because you are interacting with the query builder object. It kinda works like old school references (&).

Comment: addSelect() des not work for me as you describe. It replaces the selected columns rather than appending to them. In other words, it does just what select() does.