# Custom query inside related model eloquent laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I've been looking for the correct way to achieve the following.

- Retrieve a collection of models and their relations
- For a given relationship adjust it to return the values defined by a custom query

So for example, model users is linked to an archived statistics table. However these statistics need to be summed with various sources of data in other models which aren't easily related through eloquents ORM

Comment: Show code, and share version of Laravel.

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you look for SCOPES:

Scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application. For example, you may need to frequently retrieve all users that are considered "popular". To define a scope, prefix an `Eloquent` model method with `scope`.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include popular users.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }

    /**
     * Scope a query to only include active users.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', 1);
    }
}
```

Once the scope has been defined, you may call the scope methods when querying the model. However, you should not include the scope prefix when calling the method. You can even chain calls to various scopes, for example:

```
$users = App\User::popular()->active()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

ometimes you may wish to define a scope that accepts parameters. To get started, just add your additional parameters to your scope. Scope parameters should be defined after the  $query parameter.

You will find it in documentation.

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: Thanks for such an in-depth answer. I had previously looked at scopes, however i couldn't get the relations to work with a custom scope i.e 
```Model::with('relation')->popular()->get();```
The only data pulled back is from the scope and the relations are lost. This might be to do with the query i am using ?

Comment: So it seems to be a problem with the select columns being removed for the rest of the query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510601/laravel-using-select-in-eloquent-scope-and-query?rq=1

However answer is letting me do what i need, i'm having another issue but it's related to how the above question is affecting relation retrieval along with a scope. 
Basically you can't use a group by on a scope as you have to use select('*') as a workaround to get the relations ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is [eager-load-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).  This will let you apply a custom query to an ORM relation.  But you mentioned something in there that, if I understand you right, may throw a wrench in that otherwise simple approach.

You said there are statistics that need to derived by summing up values from multiple models.  If you're goal is to actually perform the `SUM` SQL function, or for that matter, any aggregate, there are some caveats.  Eloquent's eager-loading uses `IN` statements in independent queries, not `JOINs`.  So if you're performing the aggregate on a relation-of-a-relation, it's going to sum up *everything* and not necessarily group those operations per immediate-parent the way you'd expect.

The other thing is, if you're trying to perform this `SUM` operation on values that span multiple tables, on relation has no direct visibility on another, and you're going to have to use the `join()` method.  That's going to take you into the Query-Builder and out of the Eloquent world, and therefore away from any benefit your Model classes might have offered.